# How does travel history affect future visits?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, repeat-visits

I have visited Canada three times and plan to return for a fourth visit after a gap of 9 months. Will my travel history have any impact on my next trip? I have never overstayed during my previous visits.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking about whether 3 previous visits to Canada will help you return for a 4th time? Or if it will help for other destinations? A good travel history to a sought-after destination like Canada helps but isn’t a cast iron guarantee

Comment: I mean will officer look at it your travel history to Canada during the next visit?

Comment: Of course the officer will look at your travel history, however repeat visits are not necessarily always seen as a positive.  See this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42070/in-canada-for-6-months-going-back-to-us-how-long-until-i-can-come-back for example. Why are you asking? What are you concerned about?

Comment: How long were each of the visits, and over what period? If you stay a lot in Canada (long periods inside Canada with short periods outside in between) that can be a reason to deny you entry. Visa-free entry or entry with a visitor visa does not allow you to live in Canada through repeated or consecutive visits. The usual rule of thumb is that you should spend at least as much time outside of Canada than inside.

Comment: Last visit was 2 months because I visited my gf in Canada and then went back to Japan. it’s already been 9 months since my last visit because I have my teaching job already. This visit will only be 10 days for Christmas holiday and she will be going back with me to Japan for vacation as well.

Comment: @jcaron it’s been 9 months since my last visit. I’m visiting her again this December for 10 days and go back Jan 2.

Comment: @Traveller I’m just concerned that it may raise suspicion or worst deny entry. I haven’t done anything at all. I spent 2 months during my last visit since then I’ve been out of the country for 9 months because of my job in Japan.

Comment: While we are not in the head of the border officer who will examine your case and there may be plenty of other details we know nothing about, I think one can safely say you would not be denied entry for this reason, you have stayed well below any suspicious level, and the fact that you have a stable job in your home country is a strong positive point as well.

Comment: You would be better to edit all the extra information you have given us in comments into your question as not everybody reads comments and you risk having this closed as lacking detail.

Comment: @Latrell: please also add your citizenship. Immigration treats people from different countries very differently.

Comment: @Hilmar Japanese citizen